# In php, search in different category and each category have different number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm facing the problem that I made a while loop for the select which for the hotel it will produce the different type room, and each custmer can make more than one reservation as the same time, so I thought create a selection will be useful.
Basically, the picture will looks like this:

```
Select Room Type:
Room Type:            Your selection
Double Luxury         (select box)
Double Size           (select box)
Single Luxury         (select box)
Single Size           (select box)
```

However, I'm facing the difficulties when I'm trying to get value from the select box. the Javascript is not working by getelementbyName or ById,
I think the main issue is here:

row is a specific row have roomType and something else, I'm not sure if this is the correct way to write for the select part:

```
<select name="<?php $row["RoomType"];?>" onchange="select_room()">
```

Thank you!

Comment: <select name="<?php $row["RoomType"];?>" onchange="select_room()">
                        <?php
                   echo "<option selected='selected' value=''>";
                        echo "Select";
                        echo "</option> ";
                        while ($a < ($row["NumberOfRoom"] - $count)) {
                            $a++;
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo "$a" ?>"><?php echo "$a" ?> </option>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the class to your DOM and use it in the Jquery.

HTML:

```
<select name="<?php $row["RoomType"];?>" class='rooms' onchange="select_room()">
```

jquery:

```
$('.rooms').change(function(){
alert($('.rooms:selected').val());
});
```

you can use **`this`** also to get value.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to *echo*.

```
<select name="<?php echo $row["RoomType"];?>" onchange="select_room()">
```